# Issue with RecyclerView "addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView"

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am doing a shopping-cart within my Android application but I am having a problem when trying to access the list of "Category" which is what it should be displayed on the main page.

The shopping cart is using Firebase and basically what it should be doing is showing the list of categories available to the user once they are signed in but instead the app crashes post login producing the following error.

**Log**

```
05-24 17:38:02.156 9775-9775/com.cars.evd.dealership E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cars.evd.dealership, PID: 9775
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:500)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:166)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:641)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

**Home.java**

```
package com.cars.evd.dealership.main;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Common.Common;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Model.Category;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.ViewHolder.CarsViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;

    //Load Menu
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //Initialise Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Set a name for the user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtFullName.setText(Common.currentuser.getName());

        //Menu Load
       recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
       recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

       loadMenu();

    }

    private void loadMenu() {


         FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CarsViewHolder> adapter = new
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CarsViewHolder>(Category.class, R.layout.car_selection, CarsViewHolder.class,category) {

                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(CarsViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                        Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                        final Category clickItem = model;
                        viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                                Toast.makeText(Home.this,""+clickItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**car_selection**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/car_name"
        android:text="@string/name_of_car"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v7.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView>
```

Comment: Your `car_selection` layout has some sort of `AdapterView` – that is, a `<ListView>`, a `<GridView>`, etc. – in it, and you've placed other `<View>`s inside it. You can't manually add `View`s to an `AdapterView`, in the layout or in code, so you get that Exception.

Comment: I think you are right, there were issues regarding the XML file which I fixed using the right views for the method, Thank you for the information